# Why won't geth sync testnet blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten

This is likely (hopefully...?) a pretty naive question, but here goes.

I've been going through the tutorial at https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-2-30b3d335aa1f, however, when I run the geth command near the top of the page:

```
geth --testnet --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303"
```

geth fires up, but never seems to start syncing the blockchain.

```
WARN [01-04|15:10:22] No etherbase set and no accounts found as default
INFO [01-04|15:10:22] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.7.3-stable-4bb3c89d/windows-amd64/go1.9
INFO [01-04|15:10:22] Allocated cache and file handles         database=C:\\Users\\jeff\\AppData\\Roaming\\Ethereum\\testnet\\geth\\chaindata cache=1024 handles=1024
INFO [01-04|15:10:22] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 3 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: true EIP150: 0 EIP155: 10 EIP158: 10 Byzantium: 1700000 Engine: ethash}"
INFO [01-04|15:10:22] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=C:\\Users\\jeff\\AppData\\Roaming\\Ethereum\\testnet\\geth\\ethash count=3
INFO [01-04|15:10:22] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=C:\\Users\\jeff\\AppData\\Ethash                                   count=2
INFO [01-04|15:10:22] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=3
INFO [01-04|15:10:22] Loaded most recent local header          number=2355172 hash=159d4f…044963 td=7242707219045008
INFO [01-04|15:10:22] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0       hash=419410…ca4a2d td=1048576
INFO [01-04|15:10:22] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=2354893 hash=f97abe…ed6e84 td=7242365984708339
INFO [01-04|15:10:22] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [01-04|15:10:22] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [01-04|15:10:22] Starting P2P networking
INFO [01-04|15:10:24] UDP listener up                          self=enode://6ced7aabe1fdca76c4ff329fd68c2313498b8313520c084b2fa8ccd805a4a947d6ff9c1f67bc3cfd630a52a41146a47d29ba9302e13f746275b2fbed202d8683@[::]:30303
INFO [01-04|15:10:25] RLPx listener up                         self=enode://6ced7aabe1fdca76c4ff329fd68c2313498b8313520c084b2fa8ccd805a4a947d6ff9c1f67bc3cfd630a52a41146a47d29ba9302e13f746275b2fbed202d8683@[::]:30303
INFO [01-04|15:10:25] HTTP endpoint opened: http://127.0.0.1:8545
INFO [01-04|14:19:20] IPC endpoint opened: \\.\pipe\geth.ipc
INFO [01-04|14:19:28] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=5
INFO [01-04|14:19:36] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=9
INFO [01-04|14:19:45] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=14
INFO [01-04|14:19:53] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=20
INFO [01-04|14:20:01] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=26
INFO [01-04|14:20:09] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=31
INFO [01-04|14:20:17] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=37
INFO [01-04|14:20:25] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=43
INFO [01-04|14:20:33] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=48
INFO [01-04|14:20:42] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=54
INFO [01-04|14:20:50] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=60
INFO [01-04|14:20:58] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=65
INFO [01-04|14:21:06] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=71
INFO [01-04|14:21:14] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=77
INFO [01-04|14:21:22] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=82
INFO [01-04|14:21:30] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=87
INFO [01-04|14:21:38] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=93
INFO [01-04|14:21:47] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=99
INFO [01-04|14:21:48] Finished upgrading chain index           type=bloombits
INFO [01-04|14:35:51] Got interrupt, shutting down...
INFO [01-04|14:35:51] HTTP endpoint closed: http://127.0.0.1:8545
INFO [01-04|14:35:51] IPC endpoint closed: \\.\pipe\geth.ipc
INFO [01-04|14:35:51] Blockchain manager stopped
INFO [01-04|14:35:51] Stopping Ethereum protocol
INFO [01-04|14:35:51] Ethereum protocol stopped
INFO [01-04|14:35:51] Transaction pool stopped
INFO [01-04|14:35:52] Database closed
```

Running the same command, without the `--testnet` switch produces very similar output, however, after a few seconds, I see:

```
INFO [01-04|15:18:51] Block synchronisation started
INFO [01-04|15:18:57] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=14.070ms number=448448 hash=0c2bb8…39995b ignored=192
INFO [01-04|15:18:57] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=4.010ms  number=448640 hash=d17d2c…367cef ignored=192
INFO [01-04|15:18:58] Imported new block receipts              count=2 elapsed=0s       bytes=2818 number=448258 hash=757963…7eef6f ignored=0
INFO [01-04|15:18:58] Imported new block receipts              count=2 elapsed=0s       bytes=8    number=448260 hash=6a5e17…7df246 ignored=0
INFO [01-04|15:19:00] Imported new state entries               count=267 elapsed=0s       processed=267 pending=4273 retry=227 duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [01-04|15:19:00] Imported new block headers               count=0   elapsed=5.045ms  number=448832 hash=2aa0c4…946307 ignored=192
INFO [01-04|15:19:00] Imported new block receipts              count=31  elapsed=4.033ms  bytes=25117 number=448291 hash=3ddd4e…135ffb ignored=0
INFO [01-04|15:19:01] Imported new block headers               count=0   elapsed=8.018ms  number=449024 hash=65e261…987c39 ignored=192
INFO [01-04|15:19:06] Imported new block receipts              count=29  elapsed=5.019ms  bytes=26015 number=448320 hash=213153…9449b7 ignored=0
INFO [01-04|15:19:09] Imported new state entries               count=377 elapsed=0s       processed=644 pending=10292 retry=187 duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [01-04|15:19:09] Imported new block headers               count=0   elapsed=2.005ms  number=449216 hash=4fef1c…4fef0a ignored=192
INFO [01-04|15:19:11] Imported new block receipts              count=59  elapsed=4.010ms  bytes=24211 number=448379 hash=83feae…c17d4d ignored=0
```

and the syncing carries on as I'd expect.

So, my question(s)

- The "Upgrading chain index" thing only happened the first time I ran the command, and only with the --testnet switch, the first run without the switch, which successfully started syncing the real blockchain did not output this bit. What is this process, and is it related to syncing the blockchain?
- Am I just not waiting long enough for the syncing to start when connecting to testnet? I've left it for several minutes at a time (about 10 minutes on my current attempt), and it never gets beyond `IPC endpoint opened: \\.\pipe\geth.ipc` (or `HTTP endpoint opened: http://127.0.0.1:8545`... sometimes those come back in a different order)

**EDIT:** I do know the tutorial is quite out of date, mainly in that it references an old version of web3. I've been getting by, going between the tutorial and the web3 1.0-beta documentation and teasing out the differences.